# Removing trailing alphabet in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How to extract trailing alphabet using Hive?

For eg:

`312408K should be 312408 
81334 should be 81334`

Comment: do you mean removing the trailing alphabet character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many versions of SQL support a second argument to `trim()` that accomplishes this.

In Hive, you might be able to use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(col, '[a-zA-Z]+$', '')
```